# How to do authentication on Spring Boot without using Spring Security?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, authentication, spring-mvc

The problem is: I need to implement an authentication mechanism without using Spring Security. Stack: Spring Boot + React. I first tried to register the session ID in the controller and bind the session ID to the username using a HashMap. When a user registers, their session ID is recorded and tied to their username. And if the user exited, then the session was deleted from the map.

Further, the only solution I came up with was asking server using JavaScript if the session ID was missing from the HashMap. The approach turned out to be inoperative.**

It is necessary to achieve the following: if the user enters this site in the second tab of the browser, then if he logged in in the first tab, he would automatically log in to the second one. Moreover, if the user logs out on the first tab, then the second one should be logged out automatically.

How can I do that?

My Controller:

````
import com.cleanyco.weblab4backend.model.User;
import com.cleanyco.weblab4backend.repository.UserRepository;
import com.cleanyco.weblab4backend.util.MD5PasswordEncoder;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(@Autowired UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    private final Map<String, String> activeSessions = new HashMap<>();

    public String identificateSession(String sessionID) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> userSession : activeSessions.entrySet()) {
            if (userSession.getKey().equals(sessionID)) {
                return userSession.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(HttpSession session, @RequestBody User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (existingUser == null) {
            logger.info("User wasn't found. Registering a new one...");
            activeSessions.put(session.getId(), user.getUsername());
            logger.info("Registered an active session. User: " + user.getUsername() + "; SessionID: " + session.getId());
            user.setPassword(MD5PasswordEncoder.hash(user.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);
            logger.info("User was successfully saved");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            logger.info("User with the same name already exists");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(HttpSession session, @RequestBody User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (existingUser != null) {
            String userPassword = user.getPassword();
            String hashedPassword = MD5PasswordEncoder.hash(userPassword);
            if (existingUser.getPassword().equals(hashedPassword)) {
                logger.info("User successfully logged in");
                String activeUser = identificateSession(session.getId());
                if (activeUser == null) {
                    activeSessions.put(session.getId(), user.getUsername());
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                logger.info("Invalid password was provided");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("User not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
    @GetMapping(value = "/checksession", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getActiveSession(HttpSession session) {
        if (identificateSession(session.getId()) != null) {
            String username = identificateSession(session.getId());
            User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(gson.toJson(user));
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials = "true")
    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(HttpSession session) {
        String exitUser = identificateSession(session.getId());
        if (activeSessions.remove(exitUser) == null) {
            logger.info("An error occurred while logging out the user: user already logged out");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            activeSessions.remove(session.getId());
            logger.info("User was successfully logged out. User: " + exitUser + "; SessionID: " + session.getId());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multiple browser window with login/logout synchronization, do following.

1. When user login, set a flag in browser local storage.
2. When user logout, reset/clear the flag in local storage.
3. Every time UI application starts, check the flag in local storage. If the flag is set, assume user has logged in else show login page.
4. To synchronize user logout, you need to implement a method which will poll the local storage value frequently, If the flag is reset, assume user log out from another tab, and do logout in current tab also.